# SQL Query - Return the highest count of a version per OS Version

Tags: sql, reporting-services, sccm

Newbie SQL here and I want to have the UBR0 number with the highest count by CurrentBuild0

```
select CurrentBuild0, UBR0, Count(CurrentBuild0) as [Count] 
from v_GS_OperatingSystemVersionDetails0
where not UBR0 is null
group by CurrentBuild0, UBR0
order by [Count] DESC
```

This return  :

```
CurrentBuild0   UBR0    Count
16299           1747    2728
18362            719    1615
18363            719    232
16299           1686    170
18363            592    44
18363            418    23
18362            720    12
18363            720    4
16299           1775    1
```

End result, I want this :

```
CurrentBuild0   UBR0
16299           1747
18362            719
18363            719
```

The UBR0 will different every month. How can achieve this by using SQL mgmt studio ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select cu.*
from (select CurrentBuild0, UBR0, Count(*) as [Count],
             row_number() over (partition by CurrentBuild0 order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from v_GS_OperatingSystemVersionDetails0
      where UBR0 is not null
      group by CurrentBuild0, UBR0
     ) cu
where seqnum = 1
order by [Count] DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` :

```
select t.*
from (select CurrentBuild0, UBR0, 
             Count(CurrentBuild0) as [Count],
             row_number() over (partition by CurrentBuild0 order by Count(CurrentBuild0) desc) as seq
      from v_GS_OperatingSystemVersionDetails0
      where not UBR0 is null
      group by CurrentBuild0, UBR0
     ) t
where seq = 1;
```

If `count` has ties you can use `rank()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Wow.. Both of you posted the same solution, This is amazing!

I was close. I did a sub select but I didn't now how to get the first one (row_number(), Partition and Seq =1)

TYVM for the solution!

```
select t.*
from (select CurrentBuild0, UBR0, 
             Count(CurrentBuild0) as [Count],
             row_number() over (partition by CurrentBuild0 order by Count(CurrentBuild0) desc) as seq
      from v_GS_OperatingSystemVersionDetails0
      where not UBR0 is null
      group by CurrentBuild0, UBR0
     ) t
where seq = 1;
```